# How to Merge Uneven Data Frames With Real Data

Tags: r

**Problem:** 
I have two different size data sets that I would like to merge together. Without abandoning rows or inserting NA's. To compare this to a excel document situation you would have five columns and you would drago down 3 of them to populate the blank space left by the rows inserted by adding your data to the 4th and 5th column.

Example Data Set
zipcode = a, step3 = b in my later brainstorming code to solve my problem

```
> head(zipcode_joincsv)
  zip        city abv latitude longitude median   mean   pop
226 01749      Hudson  AL 42.38981 -71.55791  76500  85689 18081
227 01752 Marlborough  AL 42.35091 -71.54753  71835  89002 36273
228 01754     Maynard  AL 42.43078 -71.45594  76228  82167 10414
229 01756      Mendon  AL 42.09201 -71.54474 102625 117692  5257
230 01757     Milford  AL 42.14918 -71.52149  68565  82206 26877
231 01760      Natick  AL 42.29076 -71.35368  90673 113933 31763
> head(step3_df)
  tolower.state.name. state.abb
1             alabama        AL
2              alaska        AK
3             arizona        AZ
4            arkansas        AR
5          california        CA
6            colorado        CO
```

Desired Result:
One DF where each zipcode city combo is combined with their states pop and 
income. A column in common they have is the abbreviation column.

```
  tolower.state.name. zip    city       abv latitude longitude median   mean   pop 
1      alabama       01749 Hudson       AL 42.38981 -71.55791  76500  85689 18081    
2      alabama       01752 Marlborough  AL 42.35091 -71.54753  71835  89002 36273
3      alabama       01754 Maynard      AL 42.43078 -71.45594  76228  82167 10414
4      alabama       01756 Mendon       AL 42.09201 -71.54474 102625 117692  5257    
5      alabama       01757 Milford      AL 42.14918 -71.52149  68565  82206 26877       
6      alabama       01760 Natick       AL 42.29076 -71.35368  90673 113933 31763
7      alaska                         data from these rows
8      arizona                        data from these rows
9      arkansas                       data from these rows
10     california                     data from these rows
11     colorado                       data from these rows
```

I've contemplated using something like

```
sqldf ("SELECT a.Zip, a.City, a.State Abv, a.Lat, a.Long, a.median, a.mean, a.pop, b.state.name, b.states.abb, b.pop, b.income 
      FROM a a
      LEFT JOIN b b using (abv)")
```

I know that is probably not going to work if only that if it worked all the rows that there was not a matching set from A would input a NA where what I would like is that for every abv of NY the states average income and total population gets copied down the line. Than for every AR and every AL etc until the two data sets are one that a ggplot using all of the data can be created.

Comment: Why not using the merge function?

Comment: i'm new to the r scene so my last course I had in coding was in sql so I feel more at home there. I have used the merge function before but would it not do the same thing ? Insert data that isn't true like NA or null etc when there is a gap between the 50 entries and the 32k of entries? 

I am not committed to sql, I am committed to learning how to solve a situation like this in the future where you have to combine two different size data sets in a way that represents real data.

Comment: merge can also only return the matching lines, without adding NA's (using all=F). To be sure someone can help you, you might post a very reduced example of the two inputs and the desired output (or a description of the output). Do the two DF have a common field, i.e. one that can be used as a key?

Comment: Sure thing Fabio let me update the OP with that information.

Comment: @FabioMarroni, please let me know if you that update was helpful.

Comment: Cool. I think that merge(a,b,by.x="abv ",by.y="state.abb",all=F) should give the same results as the example with dplyr (i.e. you lose all the lines that are not Alabama). If you use ALL=T you will get also all other states and abbreviations, but the remaining fields will be filled with NAs.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::left_join(a, b, by="abv")` should work.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Strange so when I run this by itself it returns the dataframe merged no errors. When I run this and attempt to put it back into the data frame it tells me the following.
    step3_df<-dplyr::left_join(zipcode_joincsv, step3_df, by="abv")
    Warning message:
    Column `abv` joining character vector and factor, coercing into character     vector

Comment: 1) that warning shouldn't matter, for practical purposes. 2) make sure all your data frames are different step3 <- left_join(step1, step2, by = "abv") - it might be that you're mixing the data frames before and after. dplyr creates tibbles (enhanced data frames), which may automatically convert some data types. 3) if you found this helpful, please accept it as the answer :)

Comment: In general, I've found that the `dplyr` package uses SQL-like vocabulary ("select", "left join") so you might want to learn more about it, given your background. Check out www.tidyverse.org and https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/data-transformation.pdf